# Is there a python function to add progress bar for LightGBM iterations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, progress-bar, lightgbm, tqdm

I'm trying to fit an LGBMRegressor for `"num_iterations": 10000`, the cell output was very long with 10000 iterations. I want to add a progress bar to track the number of iterations. I'm using the below code to fit the `LGBMRegressor`

```
gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**hyper_params)

gbm.fit(X_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
        eval_metric='mae',
        early_stopping_rounds=1000)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] valid_0's l1: 8.1618    valid_0's l2: 107.11
Training until validation scores don't improve for 1000 rounds
[2] valid_0's l1: 8.12118   valid_0's l2: 106.048
[3] valid_0's l1: 8.08075   valid_0's l2: 104.996
[4] valid_0's l1: 8.04053   valid_0's l2: 103.955



[9998]  valid_0's l1: 0.0344606 valid_0's l2: 0.00281218
[9999]  valid_0's l1: 0.0344581 valid_0's l2: 0.00281191
[10000] valid_0's l1: 0.0344559 valid_0's l2: 0.00281167
Did not meet early stopping. Best iteration is:
[10000] valid_0's l1: 0.0344559 valid_0's l2: 0.00281167

LGBMRegressor(bagging_fraction=0.7, bagging_freq=10, feature_fraction=0.9,
              learning_rate=0.005, max_bin=512, max_depth=8,
              metric=['mae', 'mse'], n_estimators=1000, num_iterations=10000,
              num_leaves=128, objective='regression', task='train', verbose=0)
```

Above added only a few iterations.

I didn't find anything so far to add the progress bar. Is it possible to add a progress bar for the iterations along with or without  **`valid_0's l1   valid_0's l2`**

Is there a python code to add a progress bar like tqdm for lightgbm iterations?

Comment: What was the problem with tdqm?

Comment: Actually not sure where to add the tqdm in the model training

Comment: You can add `verbose=N` and track the progress by seen the printed out updates. E.g. `verbose=1000` will give you a message every 1000 epochs